# can't find attrmgr (from $GOROOT) and $GOPATH?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, glide-golang

I am trying to install chaincode. I used cid package inside my chaincode When I try to install chaincode, I got the following error:
cannot load package:

```
package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid" in any of:
/opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid (from $GOROOT)
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid (from $GOPATH)
```

I have used glide tool( here https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) to fix it,
now i see another error that I couldn't fix which is:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid/cid.go:29:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr" in any of:
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr (vendor tree)
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr
    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr (from $GOROOT)
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr (from $GOPATH)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/attrmgr
```

Any suggestion؟

Answer (score 0):

Install the fabric dependency in your GOPATH, `go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric`